# Jmeter URL patterns to exclude under workbench - not excluding patterns that are giving there

Tags: regex, jmeter

Jmeter URL patterns to exclude under workbench - not excluding patterns that are giving there.
Can we give direct URL's. i have a list of URL that needs to be excluded from the recorded script.
Example:
'safebrowsing.google.com`
'safebrowsing-cache.google.com'
'self-repair.mozilla.org'
i'm giving these directly under patters to exclude. or do i need to give as a regular expression only.
Can someone provide more info whether to use regular expression or direct url can be provided under Requests Filtering in workbench

Answer (score 0):

JMeter uses [Perl5-style regular expressions](http://www.pcre.org/) for defining URL patterns to include/exclude so you can filter out all the requests to/from `google` and `mozilla` domains by adding the following regular expression to `URL Patterns to Exclude` input of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder):

```
^((?<google>|mozilla>).)*$
```

[image: JMeter Exclude URLs from Recording]

See [Excluding Domains From The Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the input. i'll try by adding domain names the way u suggested and will update you how it goes.

Comment: Hi, I used: ^((?<google>|mozilla>|<omtrdc>|<doubleclick>|<pages05>|<smartzonessva.>|<googleadservices>|<rubiconproject.>|<bootstrapcdn>|<.yahoo>|<googleapis>).)*$ But still able to see these tags in my script. am i not following the correct way. can u please help here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want any of the patterns to be excluded from recording in the scripts please follow the below pattern and add it in "URL Patterns to Exlcude" it must work.

```html
1. For .html : .*\.html.*
2. For .gif :  .*\.gif.* etc
```