# Excluding certain URLs from Jmeter corelation recorder recording

Tags: jmeter

I have been through a lot of posts and solutions on excluding requests from certain domains from being recorded in my jmeter corelation recorder, but I still see those domains getting recorded in my script.

I tried entering this in Exclude urls: ^((?|mozilla>).)*$ to exclude mozilla and google.

but this does not seem to work at all, just like its pointed out here : [Jmeter URL patterns to exclude under workbench - not excluding patterns that are giving there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034735/jmeter-url-patterns-to-exclude-under-workbench-not-excluding-patterns-that-are).

Also this link suggest similar solution :https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test

I want to exclude: mozilla.com , firefox.com and google.apis

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the patterns (in form of [Perl-5 style regular expressions](https://www.pcre.org/)) to "URL Patterns to Exclude" section (lives under `Requests Filtering` tab)

```
.*\.google\.com.*
.*\.mozilla\.com.*
.*\.firefox.com\.com.*
```

and it would be also useful to exclude so called ["embedded resources"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/) (images, scripts, fonts, styles) as real browsers download them in parallel and if you record it JMeter will download them sequentially and they won't be orchestrated by the [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager):

```
(?i).*\.(bmp|css|js|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|swf|woff|woff2)
```

[image]